# Asynchronous generator - Is the calculated stator current here phase current or line current?

Tags: power, current, power-electronics, generator, induction

Please see the below circuit schematic for an induction (asynchronous) generator.
[image]

I have a delta connection, with a voltage = 380V, so phase voltage = line voltage = 380V

Then I calculate the stator current: I_stator = Voltage/Z_overall = 380V/Z_overall Ohms

Is this calculated stator current, phase current or line current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three phase machines are analyzed using one phase of the equivalent circuit for a wye-connected machine. The calculated stator current is the line current for the wye equivalent of the actual delta-connected machine. The stator voltage is the line-to-neutral voltage of the equivalent wye-connected machine. To get from the equivalent circuit shown to the actual machine, you need to multiply the VA at the terminal by three and then determine the parameters you need for an equivalent delta-connected machine.

Re comments:

If the circuit given is the equivalent circuit to be analyzed for a 3-phase induction motor rated 380 volts, Vs1 would be 380/sqrt3 or 219 V. Thestator, rotor and magnetizing branch impedances should be the per phase values for the wye equivalent of the given machine. The stator current would be the line current for the wye equivalent of the given machine.

If the motor is operating as a generator, the slip is negative and that would result in a negative value for the portion of the rotor resistance (R2[1-s]/s) that represents mechanical to electrical power conversion. I assume that would result in a negative value for the rotor impedance, the overall impedance at the terminals and the stator current.

If the equivalent circuit is adequate to completely analyze the machine acting as a generator, the machine rotor should appear to be a source for real power. The magnetizing branch should appear to be an inductive load for the electric grid source to which the machine is connected.

Here is a related problem worked out:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot! I am not quite sure I understood it. I have a delta connection with a voltage of 380 V. So phase voltage = line voltage = 380 V. So calculating the stator current = 380 V / Z_ab = around 400 Amps, is that the line or phase current?

Comment: How do I get the stator phase current for this delta connection?

Comment: You are saying you have a delta connection but showing one phase of a wye connection. The question title and tags indicate this is a generator, but the information looks more like a motor. Under what operating conditions do you want to calculate stator current?

Comment: Yes I do have an induction generator, slip is negative. I was given the impedances, and the voltage as 380V in a Delta connection.
I'm confused when I do calculate the stator current  = 380V /Z_ab (overall impedance)
Is this calculated stator current a phase or a line current? I get roughly 400 Amps, which seems a lot!

Comment: I am asked to calculate the phase stator current so after doing this:
Is = 380V / Z_ab (overall Z)
I don't know if this is the phase or line current...
If it's the phase current, do nothing, if it's the line current I have to /sqrt(3)

Comment: @xtyper: I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! From what I undestand the calculated Is current is the phase current

Comment: It is the phase current for a wye machine, so the phase current is the same as the line current.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot! So in this case I don't have to / sqrt(3), since I already calculated the phase stator current as 380 V/ Z_overall
Right?

Comment: Was the above example used with a Delta connection?

Comment: The equivalent circuit , the point marked "a" is always one normal phase connection and the point marked "b" and grounded is the neutral point. It is like one phase of a wye connected motor. Appropriate component values are based on that motor connection. If 380 volts is used for the a-b voltage, the complete motor would be a  658-volt wye connected motor.